# implementing strange calculator

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, math

i have a problem that ask me to make a calculator but its strange calculator the user input the the Arithmetical operation first in one line and in second line input the numbers so i write my code like this

```
input() # here is the number of Arithmetic operation 
a=[] 
n=raw_input() # here enter the Arithmetical operation 
m=map(int, raw_input().split()) #here is the numbers
for x,y in zip(m,n): Here i mix the 2 lists 
   a.append(x)
   a.append(y) # but the 2 Arithmetic operation and the numbers 
a.append(m[len(m)-1])
print eval(''.join(map(str, a))) #here to calculate them
```

the input

```
6
++*+/+
3 8 9 110 26 38 1
```

output

```
59.58
```

but i get 1002 and on calculator so i notice that the sum is follow this

> (3+8)=11,(11+9)=20,(20*110)=2200,(2200+26)=2226,(2226/38)=58.57,(58.5+1)=59.58
>   How can i make this in python and thank you

Comment: I think that adding `a[:0]='('` and `a.append(')')` in the loop (after your two appending operations) should do the trick, no? Simply adding some parenthesis do enforce sequential order of operations...

Comment: The calculator calculates `3+8+9*110+26/38+1` or `3+8+(9*110)+(26/38)+1` = `1002.68`

Comment: Python 2.7 uses integer division by default, if there's an issue with basic math, that's probably why (or perhaps order of operations issues). Add `from __future__ import division` to the top. otherwise you can force floating division by using `float(a)`. Though since you are using eval (probably not the best idea), the import method should be easier.

Comment: Actually, I think @Nuclearman and my suggestion from above combined should solve your problem :)

Comment: ok please can you write the code please of this part you talk about and thank you

Comment: Just zipping the two list together doesn't work, as you've found out. My suggestion is for you to write code that initializes the result to `0`, then updates it sequentially by taking each value and applying the associated arithmetic operation to it. The final current value will contain the desired result.

Comment: okay i will try it know

Comment: try to edit my code post it and  i i will try to solve it  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No operator's precedence** We simply iterate over the operands and operators and perform the appropriate operation.

```
s = '++*+/+'
l = [3, 8, 9, 110, 26, 38, 1]

result = l[0]
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    # print result,s[i-1],l[i]
    if s[i-1]=='-':
        result = result - l[i]
    elif s[i-1]=='+':
        result = result + l[i]
    elif s[i-1]=='*':
        result = result * l[i]
    elif s[i-1]=='/':
        result = float(result) / l[i]
print result
```

Output

```
59.5789473684
```

**Considering the operator's precedence** Actually you have a `infix` expression. In order to compute it, you need it to convert it to `postfix`. After converting it to `postfix` you can easily compute the result. For the full explanation refer to this [link](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/)

Here is the code I have implemented

```
def hasHigherPrecedence(a, b):
    if (a=='*' or a=='/') and (b!='*' and b!='/'):
        return True
    return False

s = '++*+/+'
l = [3, 8, 9, 110, 26, 38, 1]

## computing postfix from infix
stk = []
postfix = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    postfix.append(l[i])
    if i < len(s):
        if len(stk) == 0 :
            stk.append(s[i])
            continue
        while len(stk):
            if hasHigherPrecedence(s[i],stk[-1]):
                stk.append(s[i])
                break
            else:
                postfix.append(stk[-1])
                stk.pop(-1)                 
        else:
            stk.append(s[i])
while len(stk):
    postfix.append(stk[-1])
    stk.pop(-1)

## evaluate the postfix expression
stk=[]
for x in postfix:
    r = None
    if x=='+':
        r = stk[-2]+stk[-1]
    elif x=='*':
        r = stk[-2]*stk[-1]
    elif x=='/':
        r = 1.0*stk[-2]/stk[-1]
    elif x=='-':
        r = stk[-2]-stk[-1]
    else:
        stk.append(x) ## x is a operand
    if r != None:
        stk.pop(-1)
        stk.pop(-1)
        stk.append(r)
print stk[0]
```

output

`1002.68421053`

Comment: i want the output 59.58 !

Comment: @AmrKamal Then you needed to be clearer about what Python was giving you and what you wanted.  But are you sure you want to ignore the order of operations?

Comment: Python 2 so this does integer division. `r = 1.0*stk[-2]/float(stk[-1])` ensures it works regardless.

Comment: thank you first code Accepted many thanks to you the last code you write is the online judge Accept it thank you again